# Retrieving synonyms from an ontology

Tags: java, iterator, ontology, similarity, protege

My question is about my Ontology which retrieves synonyms from the ontology by using isSynonymOf object property. (Note that my Ontology file is 260 kb and expected to become 500kb). I am using following code to retrieve the synonyms. The performance in terms of response time is very low. It takes a lot of time(minutes) to display synonyms. How can i improve it? Note: The problem looks like in similarity algorithm and iterator.

Here is My full Code

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.jena.ontology.Individual;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.SymmetricProperty;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.NodeIterator;
import org.apache.jena.util.FileManager;

import xyzWordAnalyzer;
import cde.model.SimilarityModel;
public class ontologyConnector
{
    private static ontologyConnector    instance;
    private static OntModel             ontModel;
    protected static final Sring        SOURCE_FILE = "http://abc.owl";
    protected static final String       NS          = SOURCE_FILE + "abc";

    public static synchronized ontologyConnector getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new ontologyConnector();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public ontologyConnector()
    {
        ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(SOURCE_FILE);
        ontModel.read(in, "");
    }

    public ArrayList<SimilarityModel> getRelatums(String keyword)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        keyword = keyword.replaceAll(" ", "_");

        SymmetricProperty isSynonymOf = ontModel.getSymmetricProperty("http://www.semanticweb.org/abc#isSynonymOf");

        Iterator<Individual> iterInd = ontModel.listIndividuals();
        while (iterInd.hasNext())
        {
            Individual ind = iterInd.next();
            if (ind.getLocalName().equalsIgnoreCase(keyword))
            {
                NodeIterator iterVal = ind.listPropertyValues(isSynonymOf);
                while (iterVal.hasNext())
                {
                    list.add(iterVal.nextNode().asResource().getLocalName().toString().replace("_", " "));
                }
            }
        }

      list = removeDuplicationfromList(keyword, list);

    // list.remove(keyword);

    ArrayList<SimilarityModel> simList = new ArrayList<SimilarityModel>();

    Double tot = (double) 0;
    WordAnalyzer wa = new WordAnalyzer();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Double tmpDouble = wa.getSimilarity(keyword.toLowerCase(), 
      list.get(i));

        int tmp = 0;
        if (Double.isNaN(tmpDouble)) {
            // tmpDouble = (double) -200;
            tmp = -200;
        } else {
            tmpDouble *= 100;
            tot += tmpDouble;
            tmp = tmpDouble.intValue();
        }

        SimilarityModel simModel = new SimilarityModel(list.get(i), tmp);
        simList.add(simModel);
    }

    Double avg = tot / simList.size();
    if (!Double.isNaN(avg)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < simList.size(); i++) {
            if (simList.get(i).getSimilarity() == -200) {
                simList.get(i).setSimilarity(avg.intValue());
            }
        }
    }

    return simList;
}

 private ArrayList<String> removeDuplicationfromList(String str, 
  ArrayList<String> list) {
    for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (list.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
      }
     return list;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please post your ontology as well.

Comment: You're using a rule reasoner on the model, which is likely to be the most expensive operation here. Is it necessary for your purposes? If the reasoning is essential, use a profiler like jvisualvm to pinpoint the performances bottlenecks.

Comment: @Ignazio yeah reasoner is necessary. But i am wonder why performance is so low in this code.